# "Unknown column COUNTRY in field list" after dockerizing express.js app

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker-compose, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have this express.js application with a set of Mocha tests I run. At some point not long ago I dockerized the project. After dockerizing, it only half of my tests pass because due to mysql errors. To generate these SQL statements I use Bookshelf.js/Knex.js. I wont show all the tests because they all have a common problem.

The first test runs this code.

```
method.registerUser = (request, callBack) => {
    let {
        email,
        username,
        address,
        city,
        zip,
        state,
        password,
        country,
    } = request.body;

    password = hashPassword(decrypt(password));

    if(!testRegistration(request)) {
        return callBack ({
            success: false,
        });
    }

    let insert = {
        NAME: username,
        PASSWORD: password,
        EMAIL: email,
        ADDRESS: address,
        CITY: city,
        ZIP: zip,
        STATE: state,
        COUNTRY: country,
    };

    User.forge(insert)
        .save()
        .then((user) => {
            return callBack ({
                success: true,
            });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            logger.log(err);
            return callBack ({
                success: false,
            });
        });
}
```

This is where it gives the User model to add a new user to the mysql database. The User model is defined by this json.

```
"database_test" : {
        "client": "mysql",
        "connection": {
            "host": "DB",
            "database": "TERRA_TEST",
            "user": "root",
            "port": "3306",
            "password": "goon",
            "charset": "utf8"
        }
    },
```

I have a series of migrations that run before every test and the outcome schema of the database looks like this.

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PASSWORD | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EMAIL    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ADDRESS  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CITY     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ZIP      | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| STATE    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| COUNTRY  | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

However when the test that executes that code to create a new user is run it fails and returns this error.

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: 'Unknown column \'COUNTRY\' in \'field list\'',
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'insert into `USERS` (`ADDRESS`, `CITY`, `COUNTRY`, `EMAIL`, `NAME`, `PASSWORD`, `STATE`, `ZIP`) values (\'4909 Jean Manors\', \'New Parkerville\', \'Kiribati\', \'Matilde.Wiegand@hotmail.com\', \'Sarina_Anderson\', \'$2a$10$nsaL/4DyHquIlHKQOxjPiObBZJykbNlSZYCJCe0m3fREN4XD0c9o2\', \'Alaska\', \'01524\')' }
```

When I run this SQL code though in the mysql CLI it is applied without errors.

also, here is the DB section of the docker-compose

```
DB:
     image: mysql:5.7
     container_name: mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=goon
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=TERRA_TEST
         - MYSQL_USER=tester
         - MYSQL_PASSWORD=goon
         - DATABASE_HOST=docker-mysql
     ports:
         - "3306:3306"
     networks:
         - web_sql_bridge
```

Would any of you have any idea why these errors are occurring and how to fix them? They started happening after dockerizing the project. Before it ran all the tests without errors?

Comment: How do you run the migrations? it is likely that your tests are run before migrations are finished

Comment: What is the environment variable `DATABASE_HOST`?

Answer (score 0):

If problems started after dockerizing, maybe you are actually running migrations to local database and running application against DB inside docker.

Anyways question doesn't have currently enough info about setup to give definitive answer. Please ping if you add more info to the question and I'll update the answer.

We need to know how are you running your dockerized setup. How are you running migrations. Do you have local mysql install and docker mysql server running at the same time. Are you stopping container at some point (thus loosing data setup by migrations). Basically complete code for reproducing your problem would be needed.